# Apple script to click "always allow" codesign access is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript, keychain

i was trying to use an apple script to auto click the "always allow" button in codesign dialogue while building ios app from command line.   but the  script seems to throw an error.  am not an expert in dealing with apple scripts.  here is the script

```
tell application "System Events"
    if (exists process "SecurityAgent") then
        tell window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
            click button "Always Allow" of group 1
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

and the error am getting while running is

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of window 1 of process \"SecurityAgent\". Invalid index." number -1719 from group 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
```

[image]

any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: [Old thread but looks helpful](http://superuser.com/questions/336551/how-do-i-automate-clicking-a-button-in-an-applications-window-with-applescript). Alternatively you can `security unlock-keychain /path/to/keychain.keychain`.

Comment: I would expect that dialog to prevent automated clicking of its buttons. The whole point is that it's a security dialog that requires the **user's** consent. If it could be automated, then there's be no barrier to all sorts of malware clicking through security dialogs meant to block it.

Comment: @KenThomases I think this is intentionally not disabled because otherwise disabled people couldn't interact with the popup via the accessibility system (which is what apple script is using, too, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to focus the window first. For some reason the accessibility engine doesn't consider it to exist otherwise.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
    if (exists process "SecurityAgent") then
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
            activate
            set frontmost to true
        end tell
        tell window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
            click button "Always Allow"
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```